# Laravel 5.2 Classes do not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

### The problem:

I have an error with my **Laravel 5.2** application, where a call for a class method results in Laravel not being able to locate the class.

I run a **LAMP-stack**.

I have tried various suggestions, with many people stumbling upon namespacing as the solution. I am new to Laravel, so there might be some elemental setup that I have done incorrectly. *I have mainly looked into folder ownership and permissions*.

I have also experienced this problem when calling a different controller provided by a library. However, I am not certain whether or not describing this problem would just obfuscate the real issue.

### My error:

**ReflectionException in Route.php line 264:
Class App\Http\Controllers\SteamInventory does not exist**

1. in Route.php line 264
2. at
   ReflectionMethod->__construct('App\Http\Controllers\SteamInventory',
   'getInventory') in Route.php line 264
3. at Route->signatureParameters('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model')
   in Router.php line 859
4. at Router->substituteImplicitBindings(object(Route)) in Router.php
   line 844
5. at Router->substituteBindings(object(Route)) in Router.php line 827
6. at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
7. at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
8. at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
9. at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(object(Request))
10. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php
     line 52
11. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
     CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
12. at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request),
     object(Closure))
13. at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode),
     'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php
     line 124
14. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
15. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php
     line 32
16. at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request))
17. at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php
     line 103
18. at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
19. at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php
     line 99
20. at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54

### My route in /app/Http/routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

    Route::get('trades', 'SteamInventory@getInventory');

});
```

### My controller in /app/Http/Controllers/SteamInventoryController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class SteamInventoryController extends Controller
{
    public function getInventory () {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
SteamInventory
```

To this

```
SteamInventoryController
```

In this

```
Route::get('trades', 'SteamInventory@getInventory');
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It did the trick. I originally thought that the framework would look for SteamInventory in SteamInventoryController automatically, but I was wrong :)

Comment: Some of Laravel's magic methods work like that, so I could see why you would expect it. You're welcome.

Comment: Then why does this not work?

 Route::get('trades/newtrade',function(){
  return view('trades',SteamInventoryController::getInventory());
 });

Answer (score 0):

Change your Route

```
   Route::get('trades', 'SteamInventory@getInventory');
```

TO

```
  Route::get('trades', 'SteamInventoryController@getInventory');
```